# Forcing Javascript Redirection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement what seems to be very simple JavaScript redirection, via the following rudimentary command:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.somesite.com";
```

So far so good, it works.  I also can do it via the following method:

```
location.replace("http://www.somesite.com");
```

No problem here, it works again! The problem comes when I loose the protocol out of the string:

```
window.location.href = "www.somesite.com";
```

OR:

```
location.replace("www.somesite.com");
```

It just appends the new location to the current url:

**www.currentsite.com/www.somesite.com**

Of cause, that's not what I want.  Is there any way to force the redirect?

Comment: Why do you need to lose the protocol part? Maybe a leading '//' works (protocol-relative URL)?

Comment: Without the protocol its treated as a relative url

Comment: You need the protocol part as it instructs the browser how to handle with it, as there are many protocols relating to different things.

Comment: because typing "www.something.com" in the address bar will work the way expected, it will redirect. I just want to know if it's possible for JavaScript to do the same.

Comment: The difference is that addresses in the URL bar are never treated as relative URLs - when you type in there you're doing 2 things: 1) *Removing the current URL* and 2) Typing in a new one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to use **protocol-relative** url like this:

```
window.location = "//www.somesite.com";
```

Or

```
window.location = "//somesite.com";
```

This way, it would redirect and browser itself will take care of figuring out protocol part eg `http` or `https`

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/oyavas)

Comment: Yep that's very useful bit of information!  I can check for protocol presence and then append protocol-relative as needed!

Answer (score 2):

The protocol is required.

How else would the browser know whether

```
location.replace("mysite.pl");
```

was going to a Polish website or a Perl script on the current website?

Comment: Ok, I guess now I know that I have to live with it. Thanks)) Just thought there might be a way

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to add `http://` to the URL if it's not already there... although I can't think of a reason for not just including it yourself. Why complicate things?

```
​function redirect(url) {
    if(url.substr(4) != "http")
        url = "http://" + url;
    window.location.href = url;
}
redirect("www.google.com")
```

​